# How to load a ComposableNode based on a condition?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, ros2-launch

I am on ROS2 Humble. My launch file looks the following

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.descriptions import ComposableNode
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import ComposableNodeContainer
from launch.conditions import IfCondition, UnlessCondition


def generate_launch_description():

    ld = LaunchDescription()

    arg_frame_id = LaunchConfiguration("frame_id")
    arg_use_rgbd_odom = LaunchConfiguration("use_rgbd_odom")
    arg_use_stereo_odom = LaunchConfiguration("use_stereo_odom")

    ld.add_action(DeclareLaunchArgument('frame_id', default_value='camera_link'))
    ld.add_action(DeclareLaunchArgument('use_rgbd_odom', default_value='true'))
    ld.add_action(DeclareLaunchArgument('use_stereo_odom', default_value='false'))

    include_rtabmap_icp_odom = ComposableNodeContainer(
        name='odom_node_container',
        namespace='',
        package='rclcpp_components',
        executable='component_container',
        composable_node_descriptions=[
            ComposableNode(
                condition=IfCondition(arg_use_rgbd_odom),             ##### Unexpected argument error
                package='rtabmap_odom',
                plugin='rtabmap_odom::RGBDOdometry',
                name='rgbd_odom',
            ),
            ComposableNode(
                condition=IfCondition(arg_use_stereo_odom),            ##### Unexpected argument error
                package='rtabmap_odom',
                plugin='rtabmap_odom::StereoOdometry',
                name='stereo_odom',                
            ),
        ],
        output='screen',
    )
    ld.add_action(include_rtabmap_icp_odom)

    return ld
```

I would like to switch between these conditions(whether to use stereo or rgbd odometry) but I dont seem to find a way around with ComposableNodes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Steve's suggestion, the following is what worked for me

```
def generate_launch_description():

    ld = LaunchDescription()

    arg_use_rgbd_odom = LaunchConfiguration("use_rgbd_odom")
    arg_use_stereo_odom = LaunchConfiguration("use_stereo_odom")

    ld.add_action(DeclareLaunchArgument('use_rgbd_odom', default_value='false'))
    ld.add_action(DeclareLaunchArgument('use_stereo_odom', default_value='false'))

    include_container = Node(
        name='odom_container',
        package='rclcpp_components',
        executable='component_container',
        output='both',
    )
    ld.add_action(include_container)

    load_rgbd_odom = LoadComposableNodes(
        target_container='odom_container',
        condition=IfCondition(arg_use_rgbd_odom),
        composable_node_descriptions=[
            ComposableNode(
                package='rtabmap_odom',
                plugin='rtabmap_odom::RGBDOdometry',
                name='rgbd_odom',
            )
        ]
    )
    ld.add_action(load_rgbd_odom)

    load_stereo_odom = LoadComposableNodes(
        target_container='odom_container',
        condition=IfCondition(arg_use_stereo_odom),
        composable_node_descriptions=[
            ComposableNode(
                package='rtabmap_odom',
                plugin='rtabmap_odom::StereoOdometry',
                name='stereo_odom',
            ),
        ]
    )
    ld.add_action(load_stereo_odom)

    return ld
```

Answer (score 1):

You have shown the use of the `IfCondition` for if its true, you can also do the inverse:

```
condition=IfCondition(PythonExpression(['not ', <condition>])),
```

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bringup/launch/bringup_launch.py#L167

Comment: Thanks @Steve but I am getting an error when I use condition for `ComposableNode`. It works for `Node` and in the example you have shown. `ComposableNode.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'condition' `. 
In the above example, only one of `arg_use_stereo_odom` or `arg_use_rgbd_odom` is going to be true

Comment: Try using the load composable nodes command: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/humble/nav2_bringup/launch/navigation_launch.py#L197

Comment: Sorry, pointed you at the wrong thing